# How to display a variable from a different file to the screen with PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to build an application that takes an Ethernet packet and displays that packet on the screen. So far in my research in the PyQt5 documentation and examples I haven't found an adequate explanation of how to do something similar to this.

Currently I'm using the QLabel() widget and can put text on the screen when called like this:

```
self.label = QLabel()

def output_message():
    text = "test"
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.label.setTextFormat(0)
    main_window.label.setText(text)
```

However I am unable to get any output when I pass in my string from the Ethernet packet received like this:

```
message = [1,2,3,4,5]
main_window_class = gui.MainWindow()
main_window_class.output_message(message)

def output_message(message):
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.label.setTextFormat(0)
    main_window.label.setText(message)
```

Is there a better widget to use? What would be the best/most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code of the first `output_message()` would show a window (or, at least, that the window will be kept open): `main_window` has no persistent reference, and will be garbage collected as soon as the function returns. Please provide a valid [mre].

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround for anyone who may have this issue in the future. Turns out you can't directly reference QLabel from an external function. What I did is I made a separate button that connects to the output_message function, and did a function call within that function to get my desired output as follows:

```
self.result_button = QPushButton("Display Received Packet")
self.result_button.clicked.connect(self.output_message)

def output_message(self):
    message = TCP.get_received_message()
    self.label.setText(str(message))
```

Doing it this way allows the button to update the label with the pulled value from
`TCP.get_received_message()`.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that anybody may find this useful, since you didn't provide a valid [mre] as a context for the problem. Besides, since `output_message` seems to be a method, the `self` argument should be mandatory.